# Radio button not working in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I want to use a radio button `formControl`:

```
constructor(private rest: RestClient, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.mySearchform = this.fb.group({
          searchType: '', searchTypeValue: ''
        });
      }
```

Here `searchType` is a radio button group and `searchTypeValue` is a text field.

In my HTML I have:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-2">
        <label for="one" class="col-form-label">
            <input type="radio" [value]="oneValue" id="one" formControlName="searchType"/>
            CustomerId
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-2">
        <label for="two" class="col-form-label">
            <input type="radio" [value]="twoValue" id="two" formControlName="searchType"/>
            AccountNumber
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-2">
        <label for="three" class="col-form-label">
            <input type="radio" [value]="threeValue" id="three" formControlName="searchType"/>
            Email
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-6">
        <input id="searchTypeValue" formControlName="searchTypeValue" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to read the value as:

```
this.mySearchform.get('searchType').value
```

My radio button group is not working correctly. On selecting any one of them, all three are getting selected.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: what are onevalue twovalue and threevalue? post your .ts code

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Means? They do not exist in TS. They are the text value of the selected radio button. So if I select radio with id="two", the value of this.mySearchform.get('searchType').value should be string "twoValue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not doing binding it should be just **`value`** instead of **`[value]`**

```
<label for="one" class="col-form-label">
            <input type="radio" value="oneValue" id="one" formControlName="searchType"/>
            CustomerId
</label>
```